# In Laravel 8 can I pull the rows in a specific table and get the latest per category id?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

In Laravel, I have a blog table. I have categories within that table. I am looking to grab the latest blog for each category; as a result set.

**Example**

| id | category_id | blog_title | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | title a | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2 | title b | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | 3 | title c | 2022-01-03 |
| 4 | 1 | title d | 2022-01-04 |
| 5 | 2 | title e | 2022-01-05 |
| 6 | 3 | title f | 2022-01-06 |

For the above, I would want to return rows with ids of 4, 5 and 6 because this would be the latest `created_at` for each `category_id` within the table.

I have tried `groupBy`, but this isn't working. However, I feel like this should be easy. So below is my latest try.

```
blogs = Blogs::where('user_id', $this->id)
    ->groupBy('category_id')
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: have you tried raw sql? like, "select id from blogs where created_at in (select created_at from (select category_id, max(created_at) created_at from blogs group by category_id)a)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using laravel 8 or higher, you can write below relationship on `Category` model:

```
/**
 * Get the category's most recent blogs.
 */
public function latestBlogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blog::class)->latest();
}
```

Than, when you need to get all categories with latest Blogs, you can call:

```
Category::query()
     ->with('lastestBlogs')
     ->get();
```

When you need to get all latest Blogs based on categories, you can call:

```
Category::query()
     ->with('lastestBlogs')
     ->get()
     ->pluck('lastestBlogs')
     ->flatten();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a DB raw query like this:

```php
DB::table('blogs as b')
    ->select('b.*')
    ->leftJoin('blogs as b2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('b.id','=','b2.id')
             ->where('t.created_at', '<', 't1.created_at');
    })
    ->whereNull('b1.id')
    ->get();
```